# Android12 build error: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, android-12

I got this error after testing on my Android 12. I already tried this 2 changes:

1- adding android:exported="true"

```
<activity android:exported="true"...>...</activity>
```

2- Adding workruntime on android/app/build.gradle

```
    def work_version = "2.7.0"
    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

My package.json configuration is:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
  },
```

The image error:

[image]

What should I do?